# root can only login with bash restricted mode

Tags: bash, login, root, selinux, account-restrictions

I was implementing a series of recommendations to 'harden' my linux server, involving lots and lots of changes. Linux is CentOS 6.2, kernel 2.6.32-220.*.

I'm currently using `tty2`..`tty5` (no X/GUI etc) switching between them via `Ctrl+Alt+F?`.

Now when I login as root in a tty, I find I am in 'bash restricted mode'.

The first thing I checked was `/etc/passwd` which still has `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash` as the first line.

My question is this:

Apart from invoking the root shell with `/bin/rbash` (which didn't exist) or `/bin/bash -r` is there any other way that bash can be defaulted to restricted mode?

For example:

1. If a particular file is unreadable or unexecutable, will bash start in restricted mode? If so, which file(s)?
2. Could this happen if I've botched up the SELinux security context for a particular file? (Policy is 'targeted')

I haven't listed the changes since there are far too many, my fault

rx

nb: shell is definitely bash, since running '# ps ' lists only "bash & ps" ...

Comment: No missing file could cause bash to run in restricted mode. A strange user database or PAM configuration might cause a different shell to be picked instead of the indication in `/etc/passwd`, but I don't know what to look at beyond the PAM configuration, generally speaking.

Comment: Thanks, @@Giles. (Just got back from the run), I'll look thru the PAM config &c

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `set -r` in `~/.bashrc`, in `/etc/profile` or in a file called by one of the previous (as `/etc/bash.bashrc`).